# R Shiny: adding "%>%" something programmatically in a loop

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dygraph plot and want to add several event dyLimit lines..but programmatically. The standard syntax in the server.R for this would be:

```
dygraph(MSFT[, 4], main = "Microsoft Share Price") %>% 
  dySeries("MSFT.Close", label = "MSFT") %>%
  dyLimit(as.numeric(MSFT[1, 4]), color = "red")
```

So how can I add these dyLimits in a loop?

Comment: Seems you are looking for a conditional pipe. Does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/q/30604107/1554976

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a varibale holding the graph and add the `dyLimits` one by one in a for loop, here's an example (based on [this one](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/)):

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
graph <- dygraph(lungDeaths) 
for (i in 1:5){
  graph <- graph %>% dyLimit(500*i)
}
graph
```