# Loop through dataframe to add annotations to dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I would like to loop through a dataframe and add annotations like

```
#df.dates is a dataframe with dates in it

for(i in 1:nrow(df.dates))
{
  myDyGraph %>%
  dyAnnotation(df.dates[i], text = "some text here" )
}
```

When i run this the chart doesn't update?

Comment: What are you expecting should happen? What should the output look like? Can you provide some sample data or `dput()` `df.dates`?

Comment: right off the bat, there's a problem with the statement in the loop, if df.dates is a data.frame, then it should have a format like `df.dates[x,y]`... not that that's your question

Answer (score 1):

Create a chart variable, then add the annotations to it with a loop. So your example would become:

```
myDyGraph <- dygraph(df)

for(i in 1:nrow(df.dates))
{ 
  myDyGraph <- myDyGraph %>% dyAnnotation(df.dates[i], text = "some text here" )
}

myDyGraph
```

Similar example with DyLimits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823002/5063801)