# Conditional values using if else within shiny app using tidyverse and dplyr to group and filter a dataset

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, tidyverse, reactive

I have a simple shiny that presents descriptive statistics using reactive. However, I would like to use `ifelse` within tidyverse pipe (and not writing tons of codes). However, I´m not being able to do that. I checked previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44695376/5893454) but it´s not working as well. I imagine this part is close to what I want:

```
 students_results <- reactive({
    ds %>%
      
    if (input$all_quest == TRUE) {  do nothing here!! } else {  
      filter(domain == input$domain) %>%
        group_by(input$quest)
    }
    summarise(mean(test))
```

This code is 100% working,

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
ds <- data.frame(quest = c(2,4,6,8), domain = c("language", "motor"), test = rnorm(120, 10,1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    tabPanel("student",
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("domain", "domain", selected = "language", choices = c("language", "motor")),
               selectInput("quest", "Questionnaire", selected = "2", choices = unique(ds$quest)),
               checkboxInput("all_quest",
                             label = "Show all questionnaires",
                             value = FALSE)
             )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  students_results <- reactive({
    if (input$all_quest == TRUE) {
      ds %>% 
        group_by(quest, domain) %>% 
        summarise(mean(test))
    } 
    else   {
      ds %>% 
        filter(domain == input$domain) %>%
        group_by(input$quest) %>% 
        summarise(mean(test))
      
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    students_results()
  }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

- Please check the akrun response below. Everything is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to use `{}` to block the code between the `%>%`

```
 students_results <- reactive({
    ds %>%
      {
        if (input$all_quest == TRUE) {
          . 
            } else {
          {.} %>%
           filter(domain == input$domain) %>%
           group_by(input$quest) 
       } 
        
        }%>%
    summarise(mean(test))
  })
```

Comment: Almost, but not working. It does nothing. I know it's very hard to capture what I wrote, then this gif may help.   https://gifyu.com/image/SS6Rf

Comment: @Luis The code I was translating based on your descripiton was `if` the all_quest is TRUE, then return the original dataset (`.` - ds) and get the `mean` of the whole column 'test' or `else` do some `filter` in between and grouping.  Is that what you wrote in your first block of code

Comment: @Luis I think it is better to change your description in the post.  It is confusing because your code block logic asks to summarise without grouping and summarise returns only the column mean and no other columns

Comment: Oh yes, @akrun, and you did it right! I just realized your code is working. (For the 100times, thank you again!!) I´ll change the description and accept your answer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `purrr::when` which can help to build `case_when` like pipes. Note that I changed the example code slightly to better show how its working.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ds <- data.frame(quest = c(2,4,6,8), domain = c("language", "motor"), test = rnorm(120, 10,1))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    tabPanel("student",
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("domain", "domain", selected = "language", choices = c("language", "motor")),
               selectInput("quest", "Questionnaire", selected = "2", choices = unique(ds$quest)),
               checkboxInput("all_quest",
                             label = "Show all questionnaires",
                             value = FALSE)
             )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  students_results <- reactive({
    ds %>% 
      when(input$all_quest == TRUE ~ .,
           ~ filter(., domain == input$domain) %>%
                filter(quest == input$quest) %>% 
                summarise(mean(test))
           ) 
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    students_results()
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you for providing this example. I really find the `when` function very intuitive!