# Changing names of resulting variables in custom dplyr function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, summary

## Background

In order to speed up generating grouped summaries across multiple tables; as I'm doing most of that while in [`dplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr) workflow, I've drafted a simple function that generates the desired metrics

```
# Function to generate summary table
generate_summary_tbl <- function(dataset, group_column, summary_column) {
    group_column   <- enquo(group_column)
    summary_column <- enquo(summary_column)
    dataset %>% 
        group_by(!!group_column) %>% 
        summarise(
            mean = mean(!!summary_column),
            sum  = sum(!!summary_column)
            # Other metrics that need to be generated frequently
        ) %>% 
        ungroup -> smryDta
    return(smryDta)
}
```

### Example

The function works as desired:

```
>> mtcars %>% 
...     generate_summary_tbl(group_column = am, summary_column = mpg)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     am     mean   sum
  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1     0 17.14737 325.8
2     1 24.39231 317.1
```

## Problem

I would like, *conditionally* include name of the column passed via `summary_column = mpg` in the results.

### Example results, `useColName = TRUE`

*When called with `useColName = TRUE` the results should correspond to:*

```
>> mtcars %>% 
...     generate_summary_tbl(group_column = am, summary_column = mpg,
                             useColName = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     am     mean_am   sum_am
  <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
1     0    17.14737    325.8
2     1    24.39231    317.1
```

The difference is presence of the **`_am`** suffix in the variable names **`mean_am`** and so on.

### Ugly solution

Partial, ugly solution I have uses `setNames`:

```
# Function to generate summary table
generate_summary_tbl <-
    function(dataset,
             group_column,
             summary_column,
             useColName = TRUE) {
        group_column   <- enquo(group_column)
        summary_column <- enquo(summary_column)
        dataset %>%
            group_by(!!group_column) %>%
            summarise(mean = mean(!!summary_column),
                      sum  = sum(!!summary_column)) %>%
            ungroup -> smryDta

        if (useColName) {
            setNames(smryDta,
                     c(deparse(substitute(
                         group_column
                     )),
                     paste(
                         names(smryDta)[2:length(smryDta)], paste0("_", deparse(substitute(
                             group_column
                         )))
                     ))) -> smryDta
        }

        return(smryDta)
    }
```

#### Example

The returned column names, *almost* match the desired results. I reckon I could employ some regex and arrive at the desired results. However, I reckon that more efficient solutions should be available.

```
mtcars %>% 
    generate_summary_tbl(group_column = am, summary_column = mpg, useColName = TRUE)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  `~am` `mean _~am` `sum _~am`
  <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     0    17.14737      325.8
2     1    24.39231      317.1
```

*How can I get desired column names, ideally making better use of [`quo`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) or [`lazyeval`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/index.html)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `rename`:

```
library(tidyverse)

generate_summary_tbl <- function(dataset, group_column, summary_column, useColname = FALSE) {
    group_column   <- enquo(group_column)
    summary_column <- enquo(summary_column)
    dataset %>% 
        group_by(!!group_column) %>% 
        summarise(
            mean = mean(!!summary_column),
            sum  = sum(!!summary_column)
            # Other metrics that need to be generated frequently
        ) %>% 
        ungroup -> smryDta

    if (useColname) 
      smryDta <- smryDta %>%  
      rename_at(
        vars(-one_of(quo_name(group_column))), 
        ~paste(quo_name(group_column), .x, sep="_")
      )

    return(smryDta)
}

mtcars %>% generate_summary_tbl(am, mpg)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      am     mean   sum
#   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0 17.14737 325.8
# 2     1 24.39231 317.1
mtcars %>% generate_summary_tbl(am, mpg, T)
#   # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      am  am_mean am_sum
#   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     0 17.14737  325.8
# 2     1 24.39231  317.1
```

Comment: Thanks @lukeA, I reckon renames does it. I reckon I could even try to force [in the pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604360/1655567) as suggested by [@John Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2679518/john-paul) `... %>%  {if(Y) add(1) else .}`.