# Rename in dplyr 0.7+ function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nse, rlang

I am having difficulty renaming columns in a function using dplyr. I have already found helpful posts on nonstandard evaluation and the use of enquo (e.g., http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html and  [Changing names of resulting variables in custom dplyr function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45076971/changing-names-of-resulting-variables-in-custom-dplyr-function)). The ultimate goal is to use the function to summarise each group, and then rename the columns into something more meaningful than the original variable names.

Here is a simple example, which works except for the commented-out lines.

```
library(tidyverse)

myfunc <- function(df, groupvar, colvar, grouplab, collab) {
  groupvar <- enquo(groupvar)
  colvar <- enquo(colvar)
  grouplab <- enquo(grouplab)  # quo_name instead?
  collab <- enquo(collab)  # quo_name instead?

t <- df %>%
  select(!!groupvar, !!colvar) %>%
  group_by(!!groupvar, !!colvar) %>%
  summarise(
    Frequencies = length(!!colvar),
    Percentages = length(!!colvar) / nrow(df)
    ) %>%
  mutate(
    Frequencies = scales::comma(Frequencies),
    Percentages = scales::percent(Percentages)
    ) #%>%
# rename(
#    (!!grouplab) = !!groupvar,  # add a more descriptive grouping var label
#    (!!collab) = !!colvar)  # add a more descriptive column var label

# Error: unexpected '=' in: rename((!!grouplab) = "

...  # code to create an xtable, print it into LaTeX
}

myfunc <- (df = mtcars, groupvar = gear, colvar = cyl, grouplab = "Vehicle Gears", collab = "Vehicle Cylinders")
# I purposely made grouplab and collab have a space in case that changes anything.
```

Outside of functions, the relevant part would read simply: `mtcars <- mtcars %>% rename("Vehicle Cylinders" = cyl, "Vehicle Gears" = gear)`

I must be getting tripped up in how renaming operates in a function vs. outside of it. Any advice? I'm open to suggestions.

**UPDATE**
Here is one way to do it. I'd rather not put the variable names in strings, but don't know a way around it here. Open to suggestions.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xtable)
data(mtcars)

t_groupedfreqprop <- function(df, groupvar, colvar, grouplab, collab, plotname) {
groupvar2 <- rlang::sym(groupvar)
colvar2 <- rlang::sym(colvar)
grouplab <- rlang::sym(grouplab)
collab <- rlang::sym(collab)

t <- df %>%
  select(!!groupvar2, !!colvar2) %>%
  group_by(!!groupvar2, !!colvar2) %>%
  summarise(
    Frequencies = length(!!colvar2),
    Percentages = length(!!colvar2) / nrow(df)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Frequencies = scales::comma(Frequencies),
    Percentages = scales::percent(Percentages)
  ) %>%
  rename(
    !!grouplab := !!rlang::sym(groupvar2),
    !!collab := !!rlang::sym(colvar2)
  )

# remainder of function removed
}

t_groupedfreqprop(df = mtcars, groupvar = "gear", colvar = "cyl", grouplab = "Vehicle Gears", collab = "Vehicle Cylinders")
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `:=` if you want programmatically-assigned names on the LHS of expressions.

```
x <- "mpg"
xnew <- "mpg2"
rename(mtcars, !!xnew := !!rlang::sym(x))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hong Ooi. Does this technique still work in a function - i.e., where I'm not hard-coding the new names?

Comment: Yes it should work but you have to use `enquo` for quoting `x` and `xnew` then you can Unquote. See the programming vignette in `dplyr` for more information in *tidyeval* concept.

Comment: Thanks. I must still be missing something... Boiling down the function to the relevant part throws an error: "Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols." This vignette helps (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html), but I'm still struggling with how to work inside a function.

t_groupedfreqprop <- function(df, groupvar, grouplab) {
  groupvar <- enquo(groupvar)
  grouplab <- enquo(grouplab)

  t <- df %>%
    rename(
      !!grouplab := !!rlang::sym(groupvar))
}

t_groupedfreqprop(df = mtcars, groupvar = gear, grouplab = "Vehicle Gears")

Answer (score 6):

To rename multiple columns at once, you have to use `!!!`:

```
x <- c("mpg", "cyl")
xnew <- paste(x, 2, sep = ".")
names(x) <- xnew
rename(mtcars, !!!x)
```