# Tidy Evaluation: How to use dplyr::na_if as an optional argument in a custom function that relies on a %>% pipe

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm trying to write a function that takes a dataframe, converts a column from `chr` to `dbl`, then adds 1 to a column. I also want to *optionally* replace certain values with `NA`. Otherwise, if the relevant argument is not used, I want the function to skip the NA replacement step.

### Data

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df <-
  tibble(id = 1:10, col_of_interest = 21:30) %>%
  add_row(id = 11, col_of_interest = 999) %>%
  mutate(across(col_of_interest, as.character))

df

## # A tibble: 11 x 2
##       id col_of_interest
##    <dbl> <chr>          
##  1     1 21             
##  2     2 22             
##  3     3 23             
##  4     4 24             
##  5     5 25             
##  6     6 26             
##  7     7 27             
##  8     8 28             
##  9     9 29             
## 10    10 30             
## 11    11 999
```

### Writing a function

The function should:

1. Take in the data.
2. Convert `col_of_interest` from `chr` to `dbl`.
3. Replace `999` with NA *(**but only if I specified that `999` should be replaced with `NA`**)*
4. Add `1` to `col_of_interest`

#### My attempt

When writing my function I was guided by two resources:

1. Passing data variables into function arguments using `{{ var }}` as covered [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).
2. The use of `if` is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604360/6105259).

```r
add_one <- function(data, var, na_if_val = NULL) {

  data %>%

    mutate(across({{ var  }}, as.numeric)) %>%
    
    {if( is.null( {{ na_if_val }} )
    ) .  # <--- the dot means: "return the preexisting dataframe"

      else

        na_if( {{ na_if_val }} )

    } %>%
    
    mutate(across({{ var  }}, add, 1))
}
```

When I test the function on my `df` object I get an error.

```r
add_one(data = df,
        var = col_of_interest,
        na_if_val = "999")
```

> `Error in check_length(y, x, fmt_args("y"), glue("same as`
> `{fmt_args(~x)}")) :    argument "y" is missing, with no default`

Googling this error yielded [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/replace-with-na.html), stating that:

> Note, however, that na_if() can only take arguments of length one.

However, incorporating only `na_if( {{ na_if_val }} )` in `add_one` function's pipe does work. It's the conditional evaluation combined with `is.null` that causes the function to break. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply specifying `x` and `y` arguments of `drop_na`.

```r
add_one <- function(data, var, na_if_val = NULL) {

  data %>%

    mutate(across({{ var  }}, as.numeric)) %>%
    
    {if( is.null( {{ na_if_val }} )
    ) .  # <--- the dot means: "return the preexisting dataframe"

      else

        na_if(x = ., y = {{ na_if_val }} ) ## <-- change is here

    } %>%
    
    mutate(across({{ var  }}, add, 1))
}


add_one(data = df,
        var = col_of_interest,
        na_if_val = 999)

## # A tibble: 11 x 2
##       id col_of_interest
##    <dbl>           <dbl>
##  1     1              22
##  2     2              23
##  3     3              24
##  4     4              25
##  5     5              26
##  6     6              27
##  7     7              28
##  8     8              29
##  9     9              30
## 10    10              31
## 11    11              NA
```

---

### **EDIT**

I removed `{{  }}` around `na_if_val` following @LionelHenry's comment.

```r
add_one <- function(data, var, na_if_val = NULL) {

  data %>%

    mutate(across({{ var  }}, as.numeric)) %>%

    {if( is.null(na_if_val)
    ) .  # <--- the dot means: "return the preexisting dataframe"

      else

        na_if(x = ., y = na_if_val)

    } %>%

    mutate(across({{ var  }}, add, 1))
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emman. You should only use `!!` and `{{` with data-masking functions. Here you're using `{{` with `is.null()` and `na_if()` which are normal functions. This is not doing anything. It works because `na_if_val` is also a normal argument. I recommend just removing `{{` around the `na_if_val` references, this way you function will be simpler and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your have several problems, but the main one is because you are doing the non-stardard evaluation wrong.

```
add_one <- function(data, var, na_if_val = NULL) {
  
  var_b <- enquo(var)
  
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(across(!!var_b, as.numeric)) 
  
   if(!is.null(na_if_val)){
     data <- data %>% 
       mutate(across(!!var_b, na_if, y = na_if_val))
   }
   
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate(across(!!var_b, add, 1))
  
  return(data)
}
```

**Returning this:**

```
add_one(df, col_of_interest, 999)

# A tibble: 11 x 2
      id col_of_interest
   <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1              22
 2     2              23
 3     3              24
 4     4              25
 5     5              26
 6     6              27
 7     7              28
 8     8              29
 9     9              30
10    10              31
11    11              NA
```

First, you need to enquote the variable of interest with the `enquo()` function, then, you unquote this variable (with bang bang `!!`) in the places that you want it. Another problem of your function, is inserting your if statement, in the middle of a pipe, this does not work. If you need to apply certain methods in special cases, you need to evaluate it separately from the main calculation.

Comment: Thanks! When writing the function I followed this page: (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). "When you have the data-variable in a function argument (i.e. an env-variable that holds a promise2), you need to embrace the argument by surrounding it in doubled braces, like filter(df, {{ var }})." Would you mind explaining why this isn't the case here?

Comment: Hey @Emman, I not sure about this, but I think the curly braces `{}` are used to enquote expressions, not variable names per se. This does not cause any problem, if you try to substitute my code `!!var_b` with `{{ var }}`, you see that it works as well. Is just that using `enquo()` and `!!`, are more standard ways to do it. Copy it?

Comment: For sure. But I now understand that my problem also has to do with using newer methods of tidy evaluation. Option A: I came across a limitation of tidy evaluation that can't work in my case; which then means I should use more traditional and trusted methods like yours. Option B: I'm not using tidy evaluation properly.

Comment: Is not a matter of newer or older, but what is the wright application for your case. The `enquo()` and `!!` are commonly used to select variable names from arguments of functions. But this method does not work, for example, if you want to select in `across()` all the columns that are numeric. In this case, you need to use the curly braces, by passing the expression `where(is.numeric)` to the argument `var`, in a line of a function like this: `mutate(across({{ var }}))`

Comment: I think I fixed it using my initial code. I simply specified `x` and `y` arguments of  `drop_na` explicitly in the `else` part: `na_if(x = ., y = {{ val_na_if }} )`. And it runs without using `!!` or `enquo()` at all. So it does run, but would you still argue that it's not a correct way to write the function.?

Comment: Absolutely not @Emman. The most important thing is to get your work done in a segure way, if you fixed your problem, great! You made it! I just sad, that I think curly braces are more appropriate to evaluate expressions (or a group of functions as an argument of your function), and `enquo()` & `!!` are more used for evaluate variable names. So is just a matter of standard. By adopting the right standard, your work becomes more fluid, because you less likely falls in errors.