# R conditional evaluation with native pipe |>

Tags: r, pipe

How can we conditionally evaluate a step in a native R `|>` pipeline?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604107/r-conditional-evaluation-when-using-the-pipe-operator) shows how to do it with magrittr `%>%` pipe.

```
library(dplyr)

do_thing = TRUE

# Works with magrittr syntax leading into the `{ }` expression.
x <- iris %>%
  { if (do_thing) mutate(., Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + 100) else . } |> 
  select(Sepal.Length)

# Errors with native pipe leading into the `{ }`
# NB: the placeholder after `mutate(_` is updated
# Error in { : 
#  function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe (<input>:2:3)
x <- iris |> 
  { if (do_thing) mutate(_, Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + 100) else _ } |> 
  select(Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Native Pipe use different placeholder syntax, which is `_`. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72086492/10858321) for full details comparison.

Comment: Changing the placeholder doesn't help. The error is still `Error in { : 
  function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe (<input>:2:3)`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your code looks like you might want to change some column values based on a condition, which might be able to do without your if command. So sharing your use case would be helpful.

Comment: I use standardized data cleaning pipelines when processing lots of similar files. Its very handy to be able to call a single function to run all the cleaning, but then have params to turn off certain steps that might cause an issue with a file that is slightly different from the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the placeholder `_` is limited to one usage (see also [What are the differences between R's new native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

However, you can use an anonymous function.

```
x <- iris |> 
    {\(.) if (do_thing) mutate(., Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + 100) else . }() |> 
    select(Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why are the final closing parens needed in `... else . }()`. I had almost gotten this syntax, but omitted that paren pair and saw the `function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe (<input>:2:3)` error message.

Comment: This is the call of your anonymous function. Without these parentheses, you would only have defined the function.