# R pipe and conditional evaluation with pipe also in conditional statement

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm aware [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604107/r-conditional-evaluation-when-using-the-pipe-operator) already has answers but I'm still confused by how to actually use the idiom explained there in my case.

Briefly, the solution explained there works like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

X<-1
Y<-T

add <- function(object, whattoadd) {
    return(object + whattoadd)
}

X %>%
    {
        if (Y) {
            add(., 1)
        } else {
            .
        }
    }
```

As expected this code returns 2 if X==True and 1 otherwise.

This is all great but I want to use the pipe *also* within the conditional block (I like the pipe...), where things are becoming weird. Let's imagine I change the code to this.

```
X %>%
    {
        if (Y) {
            #add(., 1) # Old solution
            . %>% add(1) # new solution with pipe. I love the pipe
        } else {
            .
        }
    }
```

I thought that the code above should be the absolute equivalent of what's above, but instead of 2 I get this return:

```
Functional sequence with the following components:

 1. add(., 1)

Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

Same results even if I replace `add` with `identity` as so

```
X %>%
    {
        if (Y) {
            #identity(.) # works
            . %>% identity() # doesn't work???!!!
        } else {
            .
        }
    }
```

What is going on?

Comment: Change `. %>% add(1)` to `(.) %>% add(1)`

Comment: You could also replace `. %>% add(1)` with `. |> add(1)` which is parsed to `add(., 1)`.

Comment: thanks - what is the reason I have to wrap the dot in paranthesis?