eval_tidy() working for normal functions but not tidyverse functions
I am trying to write a function that conditionally applies a sub-pipeline within a dplyr-pipeline but I am stuck at applying the sub-pipeline to the data.
I tried all kinds of defusions with quosures and expressions but I can't quite wrap my head around what the appropriate method is when I want to apply an entire sub-pipeline.
What that I did get working is this, but it only works for normal functions, not tidyverse functions.
ifff <- function(.data, IF, then) {

  # Defuse function as naked function
  thn <- rlang::enexpr(then)

  # Conditionally apply the expression
  if (IF) {
    return(rlang::eval_tidy(thn, .data))
  } else {
    return(.data)
  }
}
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3,B = 2:4)
df %>% ifff(T,mean(A))     # works
df %>% ifff(T,group_by(A)) # doesn't

In general, I would want something like df %>% ifff(T, group_by(A) %>% summarise(C = mean(B))) to work as well, but I'm already happy when I get a single tidyverse function to evaluate.

mean() converts a vector into a single number; group_by() converts a tibble to another tibble. Could you perhaps choose more compatible examples of tidyverse vs base functions?

That is true, but that isn't the issue, currently. I get the error:
no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
That seems not like an output issue, but rather an input issue.
df %>% ifff(T,exp(A)) for example works as well and produces a vector.

For the cost of a few more characters, you could write out the code a little more manually like df %>%  {if(T) group_by(., A) %>% summarize(C = mean(B)) else .}.

Some more related approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30604107/6851825

What are the two commands you would expect to be run without using the function? Something like df %>% mean(A) isn't valid. Its would be something like df %>% summarize(mean(A)). Are you trying to avoid the summarize? What is the expected output of the function when calling with group_by()? Are you trying to pipe the results somewhere down stream?

No, not trying to avoid the summarize. I just have a case where I conditionally (dataframe-external condition) would want to either perform a sequence of operations (group, mutate, etc.) or not and I would like to write a function that either passes the df unchanged through the pipe or modifies it within the tidyverse syntax and passes the modified df. mutate_if() and the like are not useful, the condition is external.

@JonSpring, thanks that seems like a good solution and seems to do essentially what I want. Edit: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for, a code block in the pipeline that is executed as a whole and the output passed into the pipeline again. Thanks.

It's probably simplest to use R's standard if/else control flow for this. Wrapping the if/else into a function introduces complications that might not be worth the saving of a few characters. (I'm curious, though, if there is a good way to do that -- ie to pass steps of a pipe as function parameters.)
For instance, we can use
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  {if(T) summarize(., C = mean(mpg), .by = gear) else .}

which will conditionally either summarize mtcars or output it unchanged, depending on the initial test.

To my knowledge there isn't a function for it, hence my attempt to write one, but I think { } does the job pretty well. I just wasn't familiar with that syntax.
