Writing a R function that may filter or not based on user specification
I have 4 large data frames with many categorical variables, with the same names. I want to write a function where one chooses grouping variables and also has the possibility of using a filter, if one chooses to do so.
So far i have come to this:
    my_func <- function(grp.vars, filter.var = NULL, filter.par = NULL){
    
    filter.var <- enquo(filter.var)
    
    numerator <- DF1 %>% 
      filter(!!filter.var == filter.par) %>% 
      group_by(across({{grp.vars}})) %>% 
      summarise(numerator_var = n())
    
    den1 <- DF2 %>% 
      filter(!!filter.var == filter.par) %>% 
      group_by(across({{grp.vars}})) %>% 
      summarise(denominator_var_1 = n())
    
    den2 <- DF3 %>% 
      filter(!!filter.var == filter.par) %>% 
      group_by(across({{grp.vars}})) %>% 
      summarise(denominator_var_2 = n())
    
    den3 <- DF4 %>% 
      filter(!!filter.var == filter.par) %>% 
      group_by(across({{grp.vars}})) %>% 
      summarise(denominator_var_3 = n())
  
  suppressMessages( meta <- numerator %>% 
    left_join(den1) %>%
    left_join(den2) %>% 
    left_join(den3) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~replace_na(., 0))) %>% 
    mutate(
      meta = round(100 * numerator_var / (denominator_var_1 + denominator_var_2 - denominator_var_3 ), 2)
    ) 
  )

  return(meta)

}

The function works fine as long as I choose a filter variable and a filter parameter. However, in the case where I don't want to filter, i got this error:
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `NULL == filter.par`.
Caused by error:
! `..1` must be of size 1217618 or 1, not size 0.

What could i change in my function to be able to choose to filter or not?

You can check if the parameter is NULL in a conditionnal statement, like in this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604360/13203906

Also, note that mutate_if and its siblings have been superseded by mutate(across(…)).
